# Is Digest authentication possible with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, digest-authentication

I'm trying to send a request that requires HTTP Digest authentication.

Is Digest possible in jQuery?

If so, is this close to the correct way to do it?  It's not currently working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() { alert('hello!'); },
        error: function() { alert('error')},
        beforeSend: setHeader

    });

    function setHeader(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Digest username:password");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

No, the [Digest Access Authentication Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3) is a little more complex as it implements a [challenge-response authentication mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-response_authentication) that requires the following steps:

1. client sends a request for an access-protected resource, but an acceptable *Authorization* header field is not sent
2. server responds with a "401 Unauthorized" status code and a *WWW-Authenticate* header field (the *digest-challenge*)
3. client sends another request for the same resource but containing a *Authorization* header field in response to the challenge (the *digest-response*)
4. if the authorization is not successful, go to step 2; otherwise the server proceeds as normal.

This means there are at least two request/response pairs.

Each [*WWW-Authenticate* response header field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3.2.1) has the syntax:

> ```
> challenge        =  "Digest" digest-challenge
> digest-challenge  = 1#( realm | [ domain ] | nonce |
>                     [ opaque ] |[ stale ] | [ algorithm ] |
>                     [ qop-options ] | [auth-param] )
> ```

So you need to parse the *digest-challenge* to get the parameters to be able to generate a *digest-reponse* for the [*Authorization* request header field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3.2.2) with the following syntax:

> ```
> credentials      = "Digest" digest-response
> digest-response  = 1#( username | realm | nonce | digest-uri
>                 | response | [ algorithm ] | [cnonce] |
>                 [opaque] | [message-qop] |
>                     [nonce-count]  | [auth-param] )
> ```

That section does also describe how the *digest-response* parameters are calculated. In particular, you will probably need an MD5 implementation as that’s the most commonly used *algorithm* for this authentication scheme.

Here is a simple tokenization that you can start with:

```
var ws = '(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+',
    token = '(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2E\\x30-\\x39\\x3F\\x41-\\x5A\\x5E-\\x7A\\x7C\\x7E]+)',
    quotedString = '"(?:[\\x00-\\x0B\\x0D-\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\\\x5D-\\x7F]|'+ws+'|\\\\[\\x00-\\x7F])*"',
    tokenizer = RegExp(token+'(?:=(?:'+quotedString+'|'+token+'))?', 'g');
var tokens = xhr.getResponseHeader("WWW-Authentication").match(tokenizer);
```

This will turn a *WWW-Authenticate* header field like:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Digest
        realm="testrealm@host.com",
        qop="auth,auth-int",
        nonce="dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093",
        opaque="5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41"
```

into:

```
['Digest', 'realm="testrealm@host.com"', 'qop="auth,auth-int"', 'nonce="dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093"', 'opaque="5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41"']
```

Then you need to parse the parameters (check existence and validity) and extract the values. Note that *quoted-string* values can be folded, so you need to unfold them (see also the use of the unquote function `unq` in the RFC):

```
function unq(quotedString) {
    return quotedString.substr(1, quotedString.length-2).replace(/(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+/g, " ");
}
```

With this you should be able to implement that on your own.

Comment: Well, I agree with your answer, except try not to use MD5 to generate your authentication tokens.

Comment: @pachanka So why don’t you agree with MD5 as algorithm for the checksum?

Comment: As a checksum I do agree with using MD5 or SHA1 as long as the check itself is very short lived and/or protects something other than the password itself (perhaps a session ID of sorts). The fact that MD5 is the _most common_ function to encrypt stored passwords is a danger in itself.

Comment: Have you read how MD5 is actually used? “A valid response contains a checksum (by default, the MD5 checksum) of the username, the password, the given nonce value, the HTTP method, and the requested URI.”

Answer (score 4):

It is possible with vanilla javascript. Try digestAuthRequest.js:

https://github.com/inorganik/digest-auth-request

Answer (score 3):

You should try the digestj jquery plugin.

http://code.google.com/p/digestj/

It is a partial implementation but could be sufficient to help you get through.

Comment: If I understand correctly this would require changes on the server side, too, right? (as it uses `DigestJ` as authentication scheme name rather than `Digest`)