# MarkLogic-Rest API using AJAX

Tags: ajax, rest, marklogic

I was looking for an example where Marklogic Rest API is called using AJAX. 
GET OR POST METHOD using authentication. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Please read the (quite good) documentation before asking for help. https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/intro

Answer (score 3):

The example using jQuery at https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/semantic-infopanel is fairly complete. It lacks authentication, but http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ explains how to add basic authentication and [Is Digest authentication possible with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288150/digest-authentication-w-jquery-is-it-possible) has some options for digest authentication.

Along with authentication there are other security issues to consider: CSRF and CORS for instance.