# Digest access authentication with javascript

Tags: javascript, api, authentication

I'm trying to use the [cloudapp](https://www.getcloudapp.com/) api with javascript, the problem is that the api is using Digest access authentication for authentication.
I visited the app [documentation](https://github.com/cloudapp/api/blob/master/README.md#the-cloudapp-api) but there is no examples or wrappers for javascript.
I tried many things but here is my latest code:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json"},
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://my.cl.ly/account",
    crossDomain: true,
    success:function(data, textStatus, request){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

All I'm getting with this code is Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) problems and a 401 Unauthorized error.
here is the response headers:

```
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date    Wed, 17 Sep 2014 20:15:26 GMT
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
WWW-Authenticate    Digest realm="Application", qop="auth", algorithm=MD5, nonce="MTQxMDk4NDkyNjo4MmE4ZWU0ZDY4YWUwYTAyMjRjNzIzYWU2NzE5YTQyMQ==", opaque="9eb56ccb2e8b017ae42bdb4739690863"
X-Request-Id    b6bdbf12-f1d9-4769-a06d-216d5d7ae669
X-Runtime   0.008105
status  401 Unauthorized
x-ua-compatible IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

So how can I use the WWW-Authenticate to authenticate and retrieve data?

Also I tried adding

```
xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
```

I got a promt, I filled it and now I'm getting 200 OK status but no response.
All I need is to get this working and getting a return.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Digest Access Authentication algorithm. Getting 401 on your first request is a part of algorithm, you have to implement it completely. In WWW-Authenticate header you've got all required fields. I hope this will help you:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication
[What is digest authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384230/what-is-digest-authentication)